# Showing the progress of an PFFile that's been uploading

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

A User signs up and then he/she can take a picture to use it as an Userimage (The image has the name image and is saved in the imageToUpload) Then I upload it to the Test class. I've placed a progress bar to show the user the progress ob his uploading picture (progress bar has the simple name of progressBar)

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_image, 0.8f);

PFFile *photoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:imageToUpload];

PFObject *User = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Test"];
    User[@"username"] = currentUser.username;
    User[@"UserImage"] = photoFile;
    [User saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {

        _useThisPicture.enabled = NO;

    } else {

        _useThisPicture.enabled = YES;

    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {

        [_progressBar setProgress: (float)percentDone/100.0f];
    };
}];
```

Everything works properly the only thing I'm stuck right now is the progressBlock. My goal is to change the value of the progress so that it shows the current progress of the image uploading to parse.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Show the progress *where*?  The progress **bar**?  What's actually happening?

Comment: Are you sure you've included all your code? I ask because the way you're providing the `progressBlock` seems wrong. `PFObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` doesn't take a `progressBlock`, and looking at the code, I don't believe this would compile. You typically provide the `progressBlock` to your `PFFile` save (not your User (PFObject) save) so maybe try that.